# Center Floating Window/Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm using the AppCompat theme and I'm trying to launch the activity as a floating activity. It works however, it's not in the centre of the window if the device has the navigation bar visible.

Screenshot:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, it thinks the navbar is part of the display area.

```
Style:
<style name="Theme.FloatingWindow.Popup.ClosableOnTouch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

Setup Display

```
public void setupDisplay(){
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.alpha = 1.0f;    // lower than one makes it more transparent
    params.dimAmount = 0.75f;  // set it higher if you want to dim behind the window
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .9), (int) (height * .7));
}
```

Is there a way to centre the floating activity? Using the old Holo themes works without a hitch but I need to use the AppCompat themes in my app

Comment: do You use an xml layout file for your floating activity? if yes try setting android:fitsystemwindows="true" on the root of that view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set params.height before getWindow().setAttributes(params)